# PKCS#11 Java - Invalid access to memory location

Tags: java, security, pkcs#11

I'm getting trouble with my PKCS#11 provider. Here's my code:

```
String pkcs11ConfigFile = "C:\\pkcs11.cfg";  
Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(pkcs11ConfigFile);  
Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
```

`pkcs11.cfg` file:

```
name = SmartCard
library = C:\Program Files\CryptoTech\CryptoCard\CCPkiP11.dll
slot = 3
```

After running the code, I've got the exception:

```
java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.(SunPKCS11.java:340)
        at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.(SunPKCS11.java:86)
        at signature.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:15)  
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid access to memory location.
C:\Program Files\CryptoTech\CryptoCard\CCPkiP11.dll
```

PS. Card reader is connected, card is inserted, slot has proper value..

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which JDK version do you use?

Comment: JDK 1.6.0_23, the most recent at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a faulty PKCS#11 module?

Try to use it through PKCS#11 spy http://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/UsingOpensc

Comment: I have no idea what caused the problem.. I've tested my code on other PCs and it worked well. Finally, format c: saved my day ;)